# Extract type from variadic template class for member function overloading

Tags: c++, templates, types, overloading, variadic-templates

**I would like to have a function overload for each type of a variadic template class. Is that possible ?**

```
template<typename ...args>
class Example {
    virtual void doSomething(args(0) arg) { ... } 
    virtual void doSomething(args(1) arg) { ... }
    /// etc... implementations are the same, but I need access to the type
}
```

I tried using fold expressions but I'm pretty sure I'm not on the right track. Because I need the functions to be virtual, I cannot declare them as `template<typename T> virtual void doSomething(T arg)` because, well, template virtual functions aren't allowed.

Comment: But the idea of a template is to let the user decide with what type he's gonna be instantiating the class, so at the time of writing variadic template, you don't know how many arguments will be there. At the time of writing code, how do you know how many overloads you'll have to provide? If implementations are the same, you shouldn't make it a variadic template. Just a normal `template<typename T>` and a single function `virtual void doSomething(T arg) { ... }` will do, considering the implementation is identical.

Comment: Could you give us a more detailed example of what you try to achieve please? A sample of the `Example` hierarchy, pseudo-code of the internal content of `doSomething` and a use case using the hierarchy.

Comment: Hi. Does my answer satisfy your question? If yes, please accept it. If not, please tell me (under that answer of course) what else you would expect from the solution, that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive the class from a templated pack of instantiations of a base class template that defines one virtual function with its single template parameter as the function parameter type.
The derived class then holds the function overloads for each template argument type, that are all virtual.

```
template<typename arg>
class Base {
    virtual void doSomething(arg arg) {}
};

template<typename ...args>
class Example : public Base<args>... {};
```